# How to install Ubuntu in parallel with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

How to install Ubuntu in parallel with Windows 10? 
The wubi installer doesn't work and even the Boot from USB when trying to install does not process

Comment: @Pilot6: I understand that things have changed since then, and it is harder with Windows 10 to do it, so I don't think it's a duplicate of that Windows 8 dual-booting one.

Comment: Nothing has changed regarding installation.

Comment: Read the answer at [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/720869/481626) and do disable fast-boot and secure-boot.

Answer (score 0):

change your bios in to legacy disable secure boot then install windows after finishing this just try to install Ubuntu. this is what i have done in my system thank you